# Calculate the duration when the wind speed sequently (not cumulatively) was greater than 10

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to calculate the period, when the wind speed was continiouslt greater than 10. I have a wind speed column " Измеренная_скорость_ветра" and DateTime column.

I tried this code, but it seems wrong.

```py
df['seconds_until'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(df.loc[(df['Измеренная_скорость_ветра'] < x['Измеренная_скорость_ветра']) & (df['DateTime'] > x['DateTime']), 'DateTime'].min()) - pd.to_datetime(x[
'DateTime']), axis=1)
pd.set_option("display.max.columns", None)
```

Here is how my data looks, the wind speed column number is "18"

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what your data for your dataframe look like in your question?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `groupby_agg`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

m1 = df['Измеренная_скорость_ветра'] >= 10
m2 = df['Измеренная_скорость_ветра'].shift() < 10
out = (df.groupby((m1 & m2).cumsum().where(m1), as_index=False)
         .agg(Start=('DateTime', 'first'),
              End=('DateTime', 'last'),
              Speed=('Измеренная_скорость_ветра', 'last'),
              Periods=('Измеренная_скорость_ветра', 'size')))
print(out)

# Output
                 Start                  End  Speed  Periods
0  2023-04-06 08:20:00  2023-04-06 08:50:00     14        4
1  2023-04-06 09:30:00  2023-04-06 09:50:00     11        3
```

Details about groups:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, (m1 & m2).cumsum().where(m1).rename('Group')], axis=1)
               DateTime  Измеренная_скорость_ветра  Group
0   2023-04-06 08:00:00                          0    NaN
1   2023-04-06 08:10:00                          5    NaN
2   2023-04-06 08:20:00                         11    1.0
3   2023-04-06 08:30:00                         13    1.0
4   2023-04-06 08:40:00                         18    1.0
5   2023-04-06 08:50:00                         14    1.0
6   2023-04-06 09:00:00                          8    NaN
7   2023-04-06 09:10:00                          6    NaN
8   2023-04-06 09:20:00                          7    NaN
9   2023-04-06 09:30:00                         15    2.0
10  2023-04-06 09:40:00                         13    2.0
11  2023-04-06 09:50:00                         11    2.0
```

[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
data = {'DateTime': ['2023-04-06 08:00:00', '2023-04-06 08:10:00', '2023-04-06 08:20:00', '2023-04-06 08:30:00',
                     '2023-04-06 08:40:00', '2023-04-06 08:50:00', '2023-04-06 09:00:00', '2023-04-06 09:10:00',
                     '2023-04-06 09:20:00', '2023-04-06 09:30:00', '2023-04-06 09:40:00', '2023-04-06 09:50:00'],
        'Измеренная_скорость_ветра': [0, 5, 11, 13, 18, 14, 8, 6, 7, 15, 13, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
               DateTime  Измеренная_скорость_ветра
0   2023-04-06 08:00:00                          0
1   2023-04-06 08:10:00                          5
2   2023-04-06 08:20:00                         11
3   2023-04-06 08:30:00                         13
4   2023-04-06 08:40:00                         18
5   2023-04-06 08:50:00                         14
6   2023-04-06 09:00:00                          8
7   2023-04-06 09:10:00                          6
8   2023-04-06 09:20:00                          7
9   2023-04-06 09:30:00                         15
10  2023-04-06 09:40:00                         13
11  2023-04-06 09:50:00                         11
```

Comment: Do you know how to adapt my code to your dataframe? Replace `'Измеренная_скорость_ветра'` by `47` (or `'47'` if the column name is a string).

Comment: It is working now, thank you a lot. Althought i am not good in coding, becouse of guys like you i am solving my problems. Appreciate a lot!

Comment: df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

m1 = df['Измеренная_скорость_ветра'] >= 10
m2 = df['Измеренная_скорость_ветра'].shift() < 10
out = (df.groupby((m1 & m2).cumsum().where(m1), as_index=False)
         .agg(Start=('DateTime', 'first'),
              End=('DateTime', 'last'),
              Speed=('Измеренная_скорость_ветра', 'last'),
              Periods=('Измеренная_скорость_ветра', 'size')))
print(out)

I have slightly modified a code to see the wind speed also.

Comment: How can i add one more condition to this code? Now i want to calculate the period when the wind speed is greater 10 and the temperature is greater 35.